# QScatterSeries Number of Elements

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a qscatterserie which I got data from a text file. I am trying the calculate the mean value of the series in a function. Here is the sample of my function :

```
void GraphDialog::eliminate_extremum(QScatterSeries *serie){
    qreal sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<serie->count();i++){
        sum+=serie->at(i).x();
    }
    qreal mean = sum/serie->count();
    qDebug()<<serie->count();

    ....
```

And here is how I call the function :

```
QScatterSeries *series1 = new QScatterSeries();
serieManupulation("C\\Users....",series1);
eliminate_extremum(series1);
```

When I run the code, serie->count() function needs to return the number of elements but it returns 45415 instead of number of elements which is 312. Is there any how can I fix this or is there any way to find the number of elements?

This is how I fill the series from a text file :

```
void GraphDialog::serieManupulation(const char *fileName, QScatterSeries *serie)
{
    int number = serie->count();
    char array[315];
    int loop=0;
    int intarray[315];
    ifstream myfile(fileName);
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        for(loop=0;loop<sizeof(array);loop++){
            myfile.getline(array,sizeof(array));
            intarray[loop] = atoi(array);
        }
        for(int j=0;j<loop;j++){
            int same =1;
            for(int k=j+1;k<loop;k++){
                if(intarray[j]==intarray[k]){
                    serie->append(intarray[j],same);
                    same++;
                }
                else{
                    serie->append(intarray[j],1);
                }
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide minimal, reproducible example

Comment: Basically I just need to find the number of elements in a QScatterSerie. count() function returns a meaningless number.

Comment: Why do you expect 312? You have initialize an empty series and immediately have called ```eleminate_extremum```. It should return 0 (as it does).

Comment: Because before calling eleminate_extremum() function I fill the serie from a text file data  -I didn't write that function to my question sorry for misunderstanding- and I can visualize data on a graph but I can't count them.

Comment: I regenerated your code and added some data by using ```series->append(x, y);``` command. It works fine and there is no problem. Could you please share the part of your code that appends data to your series?

Comment: Sure.I editted my question

Comment: You've used the ```sizeof(array)``` function which returns the size of an array in "bytes".  You can use ```sizeof (arr) / sizeof(arr[0])``` to get the number of items in an array instead.

Comment: It worked on serieManupulation() function but at eleminate_extremum() function I still get the number of elements wrong.